# How do I run MinGW with a script?

Tags: bash, batch-file, mingw

Is there a way to run MinGW, from msys.bat or any other method, from a batch file and input a `.sh` file for it to run?

Comment: I want to run a python script, batch file or whatever type of script, that launches msys.bat and runs a go.sh script on msys from my script.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Batch file like this

```
C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin\sh ~/test.sh
pause
```

Comment: Why isn't it "C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin\bash" (instead of C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin\sh)? (honest question, not rhetorical)

Comment: @PeterMortensen either one can be used. If you use `...bash` you will have access to http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Bashism

Comment: Either way, it worked when I tried to apply it (part of some processing of [CAN bus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAN_bus) logging data). I got "tr.exe": two strings must be given when translating", but that was due to GCC AVR being in the PATH environment variable in the incorrect position (a completely unrelated tr.exe got started instead of MinGW's version). Thanks!